# parallel file transfer must be enabled using net.parallel.max

Tags: parallel-processing, perforce, p4v

Just downloaded p4v on a new computer and I'm trying to pull my repository and I'm running into this error. Never had a problem with pulling the repository before today. Any idea what the workaround is for this?

I tried running the command

p4 configure set net.parallel.max=5

but that gives me a You don't have permissions for this operation when I try it

Answer (score 23):

Seems that you have parallel sync enabled in p4v client, but the server does not support it. You also do not have enough permissions to change it on the server. To be able to pull your repository, you should disable parallel sync in P4V -> Preferences -> Server Data.

See this screenshot how to do it:
[image: See this screenshot how to do it]

Comment: Is this something We should re-check aftwerwards?

Answer (score 4):

1. **Goto** Edit -> Preference -> Server Data
2. **Unselect** "Enable Parallel Sync"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like P4V wants to do parallel syncing (just makes it sync files faster basically) but your server isn't set up to allow it.  I don't think it should be complaining to you about it (it should just do what the server allows and not bother you with the details), so that's worth reporting to Perforce support as a bug -- they'll want to know what version of the client and what version of the server you're using.

In the meantime, to work around it I'd imagine you can go into P4V's preferences and explicitly disable parallel syncing.  You could also have your admin enable the option using the command you got from the error message.